# run after the callback is finished

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, callback

I need to run a function **after** the `displayPredictionSuggestions` callback retrieves and stores its result in a global variable `place`.

As I understand a callback runs asynchronously. So I can't be sure that the callback is finished when I invoke `console.log( JSON.stringfy( place ) );`

How do I make sure that the program only continues after the callback is finished (without nesting)?

```
predictionService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
predictionService.getPlacePredictions({ 
    input: '1 street, city' }, 
    displayPredictionSuggestions );

displayPredictionSuggestions = function(predictions, status) {

        place = predictions[0]['place_id'];
    }

console.log( JSON.stringfy( place ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid nesting callbacks by using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: Even if the said service is documented with a callback? See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteService

Comment: Promises kind of can do what callbacks can, but in different way/syntax. Use whichever you like, it's up to you. You can nest callbacks or wrap them in promises to avoid nesting.